# Tap on Annotation on MkMapKit, return name

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

The problem I'm working on is:

I have a MKMapKit and whenever a user taps on a building, street, the name pops up from the mapView, like so:

[image]

I have my own class AddressAnnotation, like so:

AddressAnnotation.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface AddressAnnotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation>

- (id)initWithName:(NSString *)name address:(NSString *)address coordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate;

@end
```

AddressAnnotation.m

```
#import "AddressAnnotation.h"
#import <AddressBook/AddressBook.h>

@interface AddressAnnotation()

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *address;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D theCoordinate;

@end

@implementation AddressAnnotation

- (id)initWithName:(NSString*)name address:(NSString*)address coordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        if ([name isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
            self.name = name;
        } else {
            self.name = @"";
        }
        self.address = address;
        self.theCoordinate = coordinate;
    }
    return self;
}

- (NSString *)title {
    return _name;
}

- (NSString *)subtitle {
    return _address;
}

- (CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate {
    return _theCoordinate;
}
```

And in my main MapViewController, I can specify a point and add a pin to that location, but that isn't what I want. I just want to be able to tap on a object and have their name pop up.

I couldn't find a question similar to this; please inform me if I've duplicated a question.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a balloon to pop up above your annotation when you tap it. You use can MKMapViewDelegate in your controller.

```
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation{
    // do this so you dont run the code for any other annotation type (eg blue dot for where your location is)
    if([annotation isKindOfClass:[AddressAnnotation class]]){

        MKPinAnnotationView* pv = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"spot"];
        pv.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;

        // decorate the balloon
        UIImageView* iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"something.png"]];
        iv.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30);
        pv.leftCalloutAccessoryView = iv;
        pv.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        // (default title and subtitle of the balloon will be taken from the annoation object)

        // allow balloon to show when tapping
        pv.canShowCallout = YES;
        return pv;
    }
    return nil;
}
```